# iOS app has a black background and the app icon overflows to the edges

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, icons

It seems that when using the Ionic Framework to develop a hybrid app for Android and iOS, the app launcher background is set to transparent somewhere which works for Android but not for iOS, which will then cause the launch background to be black, but I would like to figure out how to change the background color to white. Also the icon that I have saved in the resources folder for both Android and iOS seems to be overflowing to the edges of the launcher in iOS, so is there anyway to decrease the size of the launcher icon on the home screen only for iOS? I will add a screen shot of the app on the home screen soon.

Comment: r u did this one like , IOS app ICON background color ---- to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to go about doing this is to make sure transparency is off for the image going to be used as the app icon and to use makeappicon.com. You may have to play around with the size of the background either in Adobe Photoshop or determining the best size of the background by using Snipping Tool in programs with a white or colored background like in Microsoft Word and then cropping the image.